# SAT Solver: SAT4J - evaluating only a subset of clauses

Tags: solver, sat, sat4j

I have a formula in a .dimacs/.cnf file as in the following:

```
  p cnf 6 9
  1 0
 -2 1 0
 -1 2 0
 -5 1 0
 -6 1 0
 -3 2 0
 -4 2 0
 -3 -4 0
  3 4 -2 0
```

Is it possible to extract only ***those clauses*** that contain e.g., the variables 2, 3, and 4, in SAT4j ? Then, I need to check the consistency only for this new set of clauses, i.e., for:

```
  p cnf 4 6
 -2 1 0
 -1 2 0
 -3 2 0
 -4 2 0
 -3 -4 0
  3 4 -2 0
```

I tried to use Assumptions, I tried to use Constraints, but I still cannot find a way to do this.

Thank you for any suggestion.

### Edit

I thought that there is a method like `solver.addClause(clause)`, but in reverse `solver.getClause(clause)`...Although, I am feeding the solver with clauses from a .cnf file.

### Edit 2

First, assumptions have the same syntax with a clause,

```
val assumption: IVecInt = new VecInt(Array(1, 2))
val clause: IVecInt = new VecInt(Array(1, 2))
```

but the variables are `conjunctions` in assumptions and `disjunctions` in a clause. This is a difference. Right? My test examples are saying so. (I just needed to get an extra approval on this).

Second, my issue with using the selector variables is this one:

A simple formula `a V b` has three models:

```
(a, b), 
(a, -b), 
(-a, b)
```

When I add a selector variable, e.g., `s`, and its assumption is `-s`, then I have the same number of models, i.e., 3 models:

```
(a, b, -s),
(a, -b, -s),
(-a, b, -s)
```

When the assumption is `true`, i.e., `s`, then I have 4 models instead of 0 that I want:

```
(a, b, s), 
(a, -b, s), 
(-a, b, s), 
(-a, -b, s)
```

Of course when `s = T`, then `(s V a V b) = (T V a V b) = T`,  but is this a deletion way for the clause `(a V b)`? What I need are the **number of models**, real models! Is there a way to find the exact models while 'removing' somehow these variables (i.e., `a` and `b`) that we want to exclude by an assumption?

For this case, this is my current code in Scala:

```
object Example_01 {

  val solver: ISolver = new ModelIterator(SolverFactory.newDefault())
  val reader: DimacsReader = new DimacsReader(solver)
  val problem: IProblem = reader.parseInstance("example_01.cnf")    

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    var nrModels: Int = 0
    val assumptions: IVecInt = new VecInt(Array(10))

    try {
      while(solver.isSatisfiable(assumptions)) {
        println(reader.decode(problem.model()))
        nrModels += 1
      }
    } catch {
      case e: ContradictionException => println("UnSAT: ", e)
    }

    println("The number of models is: " + nrModels)
}
```

Thank you, for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add another way. Using a blocking clause.

You can count models by enumerating different solutions and obtaining the exact models. You would then negate one solution, conjunct it with the rest of the formula and solve again. This negated solution clause is called a blocking clause. It will not let the solver pick the same solution again.

Now, in your case, you should add a blocking clause that is in terms of only the variables you want.

Suppose you have the CNF formula

`x and (y or z)`

and you get the solution x = 1, y = 1, z = 0.

But, say, you are interested in `x` and `z` only.

From this solution, the blocking clause would be

`!(x and !z)`

This will disallow the solution

`x = 1, y = 1, z = 0`, and also
`x = 1, y = 0, z = 0`

You will get only one solution

`x = 1, z = 1` (`y` does not matter)

Hope this helps.

If you are using some model counter, look for the option to add projection variables (sometimes also called independent variables). You basically want to project all solutions on to a subset of variables. The different combinations of the other variables should not affect the number of models.

Comment: I didn't know for this way, although I searched quite a lot! I just saw your answer, and now I am going to analyse it, as I am back into this problem again. Thanks for this, really!

Comment: Glad it helped. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The way to proceed is to prefix each clause with a new selector variable

```
p cnf 15 9
7 1 0
8 -2 1 0
9 -1 2 0
10 -5 1 0
11 -6 1 0
12 -3 2 0
13 -4 2 0
14 -3 -4 0
15 3 4 -2 0
```

And then you just need to assign the extra variable to true to discard a clause and to false to enable it, as assumptions. In your case, the assumption would be 7,-8,-9,10,11,-12,-13,14,-15.

This is not specific to Sat4j, it is a way to proceed proposed originally by minisat, and that most SAT solver provide.

edit 2:

Here is the way to use assumptions and model counting

```
    ISolver solver = SolverFactory.newDefault();
    ModelIterator iterator = new ModelIterator(solver);
    iterator.newVar(2); // for a and b
    int selector = iterator.nextFreeVarId(true);
    assert selector == 3;
    IVecInt clause = new VecInt();
    // (a, b),
    clause.push(1).push(2);
    solver.addClause(clause);
    clause.clear();
    // (s, -a, -b)
    clause.push(-1).push(-2).push(3);
    solver.addClause(clause);
    clause.clear();
    IVecInt assumptions = new VecInt();
    // we activate the second clause in the solver
    assumptions.push(-3);
    while (iterator.isSatisfiable(assumptions)) {
        System.out.println("1:>" +new VecInt(iterator.model()));
    }
    assert iterator.numberOfModelsFoundSoFar() == 2;
    // need to reset the solver, since iterating over the model
    // adds new constraints in the solver
    iterator.reset();
    clause = new VecInt();
    // (a, b),
    clause.push(1).push(2);
    solver.addClause(clause);
    clause.clear();
    // (s, -a, -b)
    clause.push(-1).push(-2).push(3);
    solver.addClause(clause);
    clause.clear();
    // we disable the second clause in the solver
    assumptions.clear();
    assumptions.push(3);
    while (iterator.isSatisfiable(assumptions)) {
        System.out.println("2:>" + new VecInt(iterator.model()));
    }
    assert iterator.numberOfModelsFoundSoFar() == 3;
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about the idea of `selector variables` as this is my first time that I am trying to use a solver. My question now is, if I have to add and maintain manually these variables (as assumptions) e.g., in SAT4j (as I am using it), or they are maintained by the solver in someway? Thank you!

Comment: Sat4j maintains selector variables for you in some cases (solving MAXSAT, computing UNSAT core). But if you need to some specific behavior, then you have to maintain your list of selectors.
Note that you can ask the Solver class to maintain for you the available varId: Solver.nextFreeVarId(true) will return the next free var id in the solver, and reserve it for you.

Comment: Thank you for this, sincerely. I did some test with selector variables, and I wrote under `Edit 2` (see up) my concern that I really would like to know how to solve it. I hope that there is a solution for that! :(